# Accented character causing problems in a find and replace script

Tags: javascript

I have a script which adapts Irish language text from one dialect to another. For example, in Ulster Irish, we say 'ar an bhus' (on the bus) where as in southern Irish, 'ar an mbus' is more common. The preposition from is causing problems however as there is an accent on it (ó) so when I search for 'ón bhus’, the script won't change to 'ón mbus'.

To find the 'ar an bh...' pattern, I’m using
{ pattern: /(\bar an) bh(?!f)/gi, replacement: '$1 mb' },

but     { pattern: /\b(ón )bh(?!f)/gi, replacement: '$1mb' }, won't work. I’m fairly certain that the accent is the problem as     { pattern: /\b(on )bh(?!f)/gi, replacement: '$1mb' },
works fine.
I’ve tried using unicode but this doesn't work either     { pattern: /\b(\u00F3n )bh(?!f)/gi, replacement: '$1mb' },
(By the way, my javascript knowledge is fairly limited, ChatGPT helped me with this code!)

Comment: It looks like the issue is with `\b`, if you remove `\b`, it just works fine.